# Editable drop down list in asp.net

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I've a asp.net drop down list which is currently binding to a data source. The requirement is that I should be able to add single new element in this drop down list through User Interface using either jquery or without it.

Any inputs as to how this can be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

```
 var myOptions = {
    val1 : 'text1', //Set here user input
    val2 : 'text2'  //Set here user input
 };
var mySelect = $('#mySelect');
$.each(myOptions, function(val, text) {
    mySelect.append(
        $('<option></option>').val(val).html(text)
    );
});
```